# Converting a MSSQL Outer Apply to Netezza Left Join

Tags: sql, database-migration, netezza

So i have a scenario here where we have two environments, one is MSSQL and the other is IBM Netezza that is a bit dated (ANSI-92). I have built the MSSQL Query, but I am unfamiliar with how to convert an outer apply in MSSQL to ANSI-92 compliant code.

I know that it is largely frowned upon to use older environments, however that is out of my control. Thank you for any help you guys can give.

Here are the pieces that i am trying to convert:

```
Outer Apply 
(select top 1 idclinicnumber, idorders                              
from orders where idClinicNumber = oGrandChild.idClinicNumber                               
and idpatient = oGrandChild.IdPatient                               
and IsGeneratedInError <> 1                                 
and idordertype not in (14, 18)                                 
and iddrugservice = pGrandChild.iddrugservice                               
and DateStartOrder > oGrandChild.datestartorder                                 
and isNull(datestoporder, getdate()) >= DateStartOrder  
and isnull(DateDC, GETDATE()) >= DateStartOrder order by DateStartOrder) 
oFirstMedOrderAfterID 

outer apply (select top 1 idclinicnumber, idservice, dateservice, 
DoseDelivered from service where idclinicnumber = 
oFirstMedOrderAfterOrder.idClinicNumber and idorders = 
oFirstMedOrderAfterOrder.idorders and IdServiceStatus = 1 order by 
DateService) oFirstService1AfterID

outer apply (select top 1 idclinicnumber, idservice, dateservice, 
DoseDelivered from service where idclinicnumber = 
oFirstMedOrderAfterOrder.idClinicNumber and idorders = 
oFirstMedOrderAfterOrder.idorders and dateservice > 
oFirstService1AfterID.DateService and IdServiceStatus = 1 order by 
DateService) oFirstService2AfterID
```

Comment: "*an Oracle environment (IBM Netezza)*" does not make any sense. IBM Netezza and Oracle are two **very** different DBMS. Oracle 12 supports `outer apply` btw.

Comment: `outer apply` is Microsoft's non-standard version of `left join lateral` - maybe you can simply use a `left join`?

Comment: The database we are using is an IBM Netezza database. The SQL standard is ANSI-92. 

Sorry for the confusion